# PostgreSQL case-insensitive GIN indexing?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

When we have a single string column, we can build a function-based index using upper() `create index on tab(upper(col))` to build the index and when the query is `select * from tab where upper(col) = ?` it will use that index. The benefit is that the data stays in original mixed case as it is retrieved but the lookup is done case insensitive.

When col is of type text[] we can have an inverted index with GIN `create index tab(col) using GIN(col)` and then `select * from tab where col && ?` will see if there is an overlap of the parameter array with the col array.

But what if I want that to be case insensitive too? I could of course normalize the col into all upper case, but then I lose the original data. Or if I have the column twice, as normalized and as original, it can work.

I have an idea, how about:

```
mydb=> create table tab(col text[]);
CREATE TABLE
mydb=> insert into tab values ('{Ay,bee,Cee}'::text[]);
INSERT 0 1
mydb=> select * from tab;
     col
--------------
 {Ay,bee,Cee}
(1 row)

mydb => select *, (select array_agg(upper(n)) from unnest(col) as n) from tab;
     col      |  array_agg
--------------+--------------
 {Ay,bee,Cee} | {AY,BEE,CEE}
(1 row)

mydb=> alter table tab add column norm text[] generated always as (select array_agg(upper(n)) from unnest(col) as n);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: ...e tab add column norm text[] generated always as (select arr...
                                                             ^
```

If that had worked, I could probably have created the GIN index on the norm column. But alas, it didn't. Any other solution?

Comment: @jjanes Sorry you are right I am deleting the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your subquery into a helper function:

```
create or replace function upper_array(text[]) returns text[] language sql as $$
   select array_agg(upper(unnest)) from unnest($1)
$$ immutable parallel safe;
```

Then rather than add a generated column which takes extra space, I'd probably just define the index over the function directly:

```
create index on tab using gin (upper_array(col));
```

Comment: This is cool. What I did was to use the same function name upper (and lower) and have the parameter polymorphism do the rest, so I can just say `create index on tab using gin (upper(col));`

Comment: There is still a lingering question which would be faster, `select array_agg(upper(unnest)) from unnest($1)` or `select upper($1::text)::text[]`? I bet the second approach is faster.

Comment: The casting method is indeed faster by 3 to 4 times.  But given that the cast from text[] to text is marked as not immutable for reasons I don't understand, I'd be reluctant to override that when a cleaner option is available.  It seems like premature optimization to me, unless you already know that this will be a major bottleneck on your system.

Comment: I supposed it's a matter of personality. I am more of an adventurer and would discount the rare corner case where text[]::text would lead to different results when invoked at different times. Perhaps it is related to the string representation of the array to be configurable (the delim-comma, for example). But since we are immediately converting back to text[] any such effect of configurations will be cancelled out immediately.